# Visual Studio 2019 - Use PowerShell to open files instead of Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, navigation

I'm looking to use PowerShell as an alternative to Solution Explorer.

For example, you can open a file in VS Code by running this command (assuming the `.exe` is in the `$PATH` variable):

```
ps>code C:\repo\path\to\file.cs
```

It would be nice if could do the same with Visual Studio:

```
ps>vs C:\repo\path\to\file.cs
```

And for those of you asking *why*, I truly believe this is a faster way. Especially since `Ctrl` + `,` doesn't do well with something like `index.cshtml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean you want to open C:\repo\path\to\file.cs in Visual Studio using Powershell?

devenv.exe C:\repo\path\to\file.cs

Comment: I also found out you can do it in Rider by doing this: `rider64.exe C:\repo\path\to\file.cs`

Comment: When using this command (even from within the integrated VS Developer Shell) it opens a new instance of Visual Studio, rather than an existing instance already running. Do you happen to have any idea how to achieve opening the file in an existing instance?

Comment: You can ensure that your file opens in an existing instance of visual studio instead of a new instance by doing the following:
`devenv.exe /edit C:\path\to\file.cs`